# Angular JS - Front end web development framework?

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs, node.js, spring-boot

I am confused by the term Angular JS being a front end web development framework and (Spring MVC or Node Js) being a back end or simply web development framework.

My question is:

1. Can I built a full fledged web application which interacts with an application server like Tomcat and MySQL using just Angular JS?
2. If answer is "no" to 1(above), then my understanding is that I learn Angular JS for front end and (Spring Boot or Node JS) for back end. If that is the case what role does Angular JS play, which HTML, CSS and JavaScript already does not play?
3. If I use Angular JS, how does HTML, CSS and Javascript which were used traditionally fit in the picture?

I know there are lot of resources in the web but I am still not very clear.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No, you cannot build a full fledged web app in AngularJs. AngularJs is a JavaScript framework that runs in the browser (front end), not on the server (back end). Unless your application is very simple, your AngularJs application will interact with service(s) to get and set data.
2. Before even talking about AnglarJs' features, one aspect that a framework gives you is a pattern and guidelines that help with organising your code. If you start writing code without any framework, you have to invest more effort in thinking about how to structure your code. While you still have to do that with a framework, there are usually guidelines that are established by the community that will help you as the code base grows. Now, AngularJs is a Single Page Application (SPA) framework. That means that one of the features that AngularJs gives you is client-side (browser) routing. That allows you to only change the sections of the page that actually need to change instead of refreshing the whole page, resulting in a nicer user experience. AngularJs also gives you two-way data binding. Two-way data binding will automatically reflect JavaScript model changes in your DOM, and vise-versa. In vanilla JavaScript, if a values changes and you want to show that value in the DOM, then you need to write code that will actually apply that change in the DOM. With AngularJs' two-way data binding, that is taken care for you. AngularJs has many more features (dependency injection, components, directives, filters, etc.) that you can all find on the web, but hopefully the two examples I gave you give you an idea.
3. From my answer to question 2, you may realise now that you will still use HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. AngularJs is not a language, but a framework built on top of those languages.

By the way, at this stage I would not recommend building a new app with [AngularJs](https://angularjs.org/). Use [Angular](https://angular.io/) instead. Angular is the successor of AngularJs.